# Wubi downloaded and installed 64bit 12.10 on my 32bit netbook

Tags: wubi, 32-bit

I downloaded the Wubi installer on my atom N450 netbook. When I started up Ubuntu I got an error that read failed to change the mode of /ect/passwd- to 0600. Then while it booted it froze and several strange characters filled the screen. Finally it loaded it ran pretty slow, and I could connect to my router, but not to the internet. Ping 8.8.8.8 showed no server found.

So I checked the about computer and it said I was running the 64 bit installation. Now I know that my computer has a low power 32 bit chip and even the Ubuntu iso download suggested a 32 bit installation. So I went to double check and see if I just missed the option for a 32 bit Wubi install and I did not. There was no option. Is there any way to download a 32 bit version of 12.10 through the Wubi?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your best shot is to install it by Wubi. You should try to download the 32-bit ISO from the Ubuntu site (via Torrent or alternate) and then mount it on a virtual drive, burn it on a disc or mount it via USB. This should get the installation work properly. Have a nice day!